# Value matching multiple values in an array but with array indexing

Tags: r

I'm sure this is probably absurdly simple, but for whatever reason I can't find any relevant documentation anywhere.

I have a multidimensional array we'll call `m1` and a vector of values we'll call `v1`.

I know each element contained in `v1` exists somewhere in `m1` and I'd like to know where. The issue is that I also want to know the location in terms of array indexing.

So, say (simplified example):

```
m1< array(c(3,9,110,2,36,0.01,-9,11,95,67,31,-2,2.5,10,1,49),dim=c(4,2,2))
v1<-c(110,36)

> m1

, , 1

    [,1] [,2]
[1,] 3   36
[2,] 9   0.5
[3,] 110 -9
[4,] 2   11

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   95  2.5
[2,]   67  10
[3,]   31  1
[4,]   -2  49

> v1
[1] 110 36
```

I would like the output of some function f(m1,v1) to give me something like:

```
3 1 1
1 2 1
```

If I were to do this with `which`, I would do something like `which(m1==v1,arr.ind=T)`, however it won't work with a vector of values to match (it seems).

Otherwise I could use `match` - `match(v1,m1)` - however this will return the location in vector form (apologies if this is not the correct terminology) not array indexing form - so 3 and 5 in the above example.

What can I do to get the output I'm looking for? Alternatively, is there an easy way to convert a vector form location to the same but in array index form? It's simple in the above case but when I'm dealing with multiple dimensions it becomes a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `m1` and `v1` from your example:

```
vapply(X = v1,
       FUN = function(x) which(x == m1, arr.ind = TRUE),
       FUN.VALUE = integer(length(dim(m1)))
       )
```

This returns

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    1
```

Each column has the indices for one of the values.